# How to get a button's ID when clicked in Windows 8 apps?

Tags: javascript, html, click, windows-8.1, dom-events

I'm trying to get the ID of the button I clicked but I can't do it. I tried everything but it doesn't work.

How can I do this?
[image: It saves the last value which is resetBttn]

Comment: Please show your code.

Comment: Does `this.id` work inside the click handler?

Comment: I added a picture of my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works on an ordinary webpage:

```js
var update = function(el) {
  document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = el.id;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="update(this)" id="btn1">btn1</button>
<button onclick="update(this)" id="btn2">btn2</button>
<span id="msg">ID goes here</span>
```

But it's better to use event listeners:

```js
var update = function(el) {
  document.getElementById("msg").innerHTML = el.id;
}

document.getElementById("btn1").addEventListener("click", function() {
  update(this);
});

document.getElementById("btn2").addEventListener("click", function() {
  update(this);
});
```

```html
<button id="btn1">btn1</button>
<button id="btn2">btn2</button>
<span id="msg">ID goes here</span>
```

That second method also works with Windows 8.1 apps.

Comment: Updated, check it out?

Comment: It's worked, the second option, thank you very much! (Try to edit your answer and erase the first option)

Comment: Your welcome! I'll edit it, not erase it, just point out that the second option is better. ;)